# Store coordinates in a union for two different ways of access

Tags: c, struct, union

I want to create a typedef that holds cartesian coordinates of a 3D point, and gives two different ways to access these coordinates.
Ideally, if my variable is point3D, I would like to be able to write both of these :

```
point3D->x = 0.0;
point3D->y = 0.0;
point3D->z = 0.0;
```

AND

```
point3D[x] = 0.0;
point3D[y] = 0.0;
point3D[z] = 0.0;
```

I know that unions could do the trick. But, I do not know how to use it without creating intermediate structure/array names inside of it.

Is there a proper way to do it as shown above ?

Comment: I think that the answers to the other question should meet your requirements. Just ping me here in a comment if your problem is different.

Comment: Thank you. This works fine. But, there is no way to avoid the intermediate field "coords" for array access ?

Comment: If you want to write a nice and conformant C code, I know no other way...

Comment: I think I am okay with that. Thank you